# Auto Generated Checkboxes - Check if checked C#

Tags: c#

I need to get the values and ids of the check boxes that are checked only.

index.aspx

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Download Files" OnClick="LoadFiles" />
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="SubCategory" />
```

Code Behind

Auto Generated Checkboxes:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");      
SqlDataReader dr = null;
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (dr.Read())
{
    sb.Append("<input runat=\"server\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"" + dr["Attachment_Name"].ToString() + "\" name=\"chk_" + dr["Attachment_ID"].ToString() + "\">" + dr["Attachment_Name"].ToString() + "</input>&nbsp;&nbsp;");
}
dr.NextResult();

SubCategory.Text = sb.ToString();
```

I have tried this but this only worked if it is a CheckboxList: (this code is from another project of mine)

```
string values = "";

foreach (ListItem objItem in chkTopics.Items)
{
    if (objItem.Selected)
    {
        values += objItem.Value + ":";
    }
}
```

Kind of stumped here on this.

Comment: Are you re-generating the checkboxes on postback?

Comment: Sorry I do not follow you.  I would need to check into that. Sorry. I havent done that before. lol. If you have any examples of it then I can give it a shot.

Comment: @akorenchikov shows this in his answer

Answer (score 0):

I have created a sample page according to your requirements.I hope it will help you
Markup:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="SOA.aspx.cs" Inherits="SOA" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="checkboxesHolder" runat="server">
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Server side:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class SOA : System.Web.UI.Page {
    private List<String> GetNames() {
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(x => string.Format("Checkbox_{0}", x)).ToList();
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        CreateCheckboxes();
        if(IsPostBack)
            ReadCheckboxes();
    }

    private void ReadCheckboxes() {
        var selectedName = GetNames().Where(x => Request.Form[x] == "checked");
    }

    private void CreateCheckboxes() {
        foreach(var name in GetNames()) {
            var checkbox = new HtmlInputCheckBox();
            checkbox.ID = name;
            checkbox.Value = "checked";
            checkbox.Name = name;
            checkboxesHolder.Controls.Add(checkbox);
            checkboxesHolder.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(name));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Form sends checkbox's value if it's checked, so you can just check that necessary key is presented in Request.Form.Keys during postback

Comment: I do not see this.  I am creating a Checkbox via a String Builder and then putting it into a ASP:LITERAL on the main page....